# What are some software/filters to manage Internet use and time on Ubuntu?

Tags: time-management

I am aware of some software like Willow, DansGuardian, SquidGuard and Pluckeye. Many seem to be old or not so active, so I thought that maybe I am  not searching with the right words.

Just to be clear, I am the root user and this is not for parental purpose.

I would like to block some websites for most time and track my time on a browser (Brave).

Answer (score 0):

That is quite what is now opensource, better for free you wont get. I would use Pfsense for example or Endian Firewall the Community version.